# python: strange behavior related to class function address, especially when using copy.deepcopy()

Tags: python, class, dictionary, copy, function-pointers

Consider the following code:

```
class class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = None
        print('class1.__init__() at       %s'%str(hex(id(self))))

    def run(self):
        self.var = 1
        print("func1() address            %s->%s" % (str(hex(id(self))), str(hex(id(self.func1)))))
        self.func1(' directly ')
        dict1 = {
            "func1": self.func1,
        }
        print("func1() address in dict1   %s->%s" % (str(hex(id(self))), str(hex(id(dict1['func1'])))))
        self.var = 2
        dict1['func1']('via dict1 ')
        dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
        print("func1() address in dict2   %s->%s" % (str(hex(id(self))), str(hex(id(dict2['func1'])))))
        self.var = 3
        dict2['func1']('via dict2 ')

    def func1(self, context):
        print('called func1(%s)   %s->%s, var=%i'%(context, str(hex(id(self))), str(hex(id(self.func1))), self.var))
        print('called func1(%s)   %s->%s, var=%i'%(context, str(hex(id(self))), str(hex(id(self.func1))), self.var))

cl1 = class1()
cl1.run()
```

and result in python 3.10:

```
class1.__init__() at       0x1c24355bf10
func1() address            0x1c24355bf10->0x1c24354bb40
called func1( directly )   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c24354bbc0, var=1
called func1( directly )   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c24354bb40, var=1
func1() address in dict1   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c24354bb40
called func1(via dict1 )   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c2435640c0, var=2
called func1(via dict1 )   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c2435640c0, var=2
func1() address in dict2   0x1c24355bf10->0x1c2435640c0
called func1(via dict2 )   0x1c24355bbe0->0x1c243564180, var=2
called func1(via dict2 )   0x1c24355bbe0->0x1c243564180, var=2
```

There are several issues which I don't understand

1. In some cases getting function address/reference via id() give two different values [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e78IY.png) though calling them indicates it's the same function in same class
2. Address of function in dictionary and address of called function differ [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Kgi.png)
3. Upon making a copy.deepcopy() of dictionary the address of function in new dictionary same as address of called function from bullet-point (2)  (orange on pic) but calling the function via pointer in dictionary indicates that deepcopy cloned the class object as well as dictionary with function pointer - it got different address (yellow on pic) and self.var contains the pre-deepcopy() state (blue on pic) [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84m2C.png)

Comment: Method objects are generated on every access. They're not a persistent part of an object's state.

Comment: Though they may have the same address and also not more than two